# QueryOver filtering on collection of strings: NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have items. Each item belongs to a group. And each item owns a (possibly empty) list of tags (strings) useful for boosting text search. The search should find items matching their description, description of the group they belong to or one or more tags (all in OR conditions).

I'm trying to select items by a search key through the following QueryOver.

```
Item i = null;
ItemGroup g = null;
String tag = null;

session
    .QueryOver<Item>(() => i)
    .JoinAlias(x => x.Group, () => g, JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .JoinAlias(x => x.Tags, () => tag, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin) //left outher join because it is possible for an item to have no tags at all.
    .Where(
        new Disjunction()
            .Add(Restrictions.On(() => p.Description).IsInsensitiveLike(searchKey, MatchMode.Anywhere))
            .Add(Restrictions.On(() => g.Description).IsInsensitiveLike(searchKey, MatchMode.Start))
            .Add(Restrictions.On(() => tag).IsInsensitiveLike(searchKey, MatchMode.Start)) //this condition throws an exception
    )
    .Take(maxResults)
    .Future();
```

Item class is mapped as follows:

```
<class name="Item" table="Items">
<id name="Id">
    <generator class="guid.comb" />
</id>

    <natural-id>
        <property name="Code" not-null="true" />
    </natural-id>
    <property name="Description" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="Group" column="ID_Group" not-null="true" fetch="join" />
    <property name="ExpiryDate" />
    <list name="Tags" table="Items_Tags">
        <key column="ID_Item" />
        <index column="Idx" />
        <element column="Tag" />
    </list>
</class>
```

Query execution throws a NullReferenceException. Removing the last condition in the disjunction the exception is not thrown.

I didn't get rid of this without using magic strings.

Comment: .Add(Restrictions.On(() => tag).IsInsensitiveLike(searchKey, MatchMode.Start)) tag on this line should be tag.Tag because you have defined alias of Tags table as tag but not mentioned field in Search

Comment: tag is a plain String object. It has not a Tag property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked recently, but as far as I know NHibernate doesn't support querying over collections of values using the QueryOver or Criteria API directly.

I would suggest that your best workaround is to use a SQLCriteria:

```
        var tagCriteria = new SQLCriterion(
            new SqlString("{alias}.Id IN (SELECT ID_Item FROM Items_Tags WHERE Tag LIKE ?)"),
            new[] {searchKey + "%"},
            new[] {NHibernateUtil.String}
            );

        session
            .QueryOver<Item>(() => i)
            .JoinAlias(x => x.Group, () => g, JoinType.InnerJoin)
            .Where(
                new Disjunction()
                    .Add(Restrictions.On(() => p.Description).IsInsensitiveLike(searchKey, MatchMode.Anywhere))
                    .Add(Restrictions.On(() => g.Description).IsInsensitiveLike(searchKey, MatchMode.Start))
                    .Add(tagCriteria)
            )
            .Take(maxResults)
            .Future();
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why, but as soon as I add a criterium to the disjunction, the query does not get executed at all, without exceptions. This happens even if the SqlCriterium is defined as follows (no sense, but it should work): new SQLCriterion(new SqlString("{alias}.Id = ?"), new[] {searchKey + "%"}, new[] {NHibernateUtil.String});

Comment: @Marcello Instead of new SqlString try SqlString.Parse .

Comment: @Marcello "new SqlString" doesn't "parse" the string in search of parameters, "SqlString.Parse" does.

Answer (score 1):

use this, Please correct me if I misunderstood

```
session
    .QueryOver<Item>(() => i)
    .JoinAlias(x => x.Group, () => g, JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .JoinAlias(x => x.Tags, () => tag, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin) //left outher join because it is possible for an item to have no tags at all.
    .Where(
        new Disjunction()
            .Add(Restrictions.On(() => p.Description).IsInsensitiveLike(searchKey, MatchMode.Anywhere))
            .Add(Restrictions.On(() => g.Description).IsInsensitiveLike(searchKey, MatchMode.Start))
            .Add(Restrictions.On(() => tag.Tag).IsInsensitiveLike(searchKey, MatchMode.Start)) //this condition throws an exception
    )
    .Take(maxResults)
    .Future();
```

Comment: Actually, tag is a string. It does not have a Tag property.

Comment: you have referred, Tags as tag, and you should use Tags.Tag property in order to search it. Have you tried the code?

Comment: I tried your code. It does not compile. tag is just a plain String object. I tried also replacing my "() => tag" with "() => i.Tags". In this last case, the query against the DB is not fired at all and an empty result set is returned with no exception. Sorry if I didn't understand your suggestion. Try to be more precise.